# How to save class method's meta data in Python

Tags: python, function, arguments, dry, inspect

I have a Python class with several different methods doing different things, but I'd like each of them, when it runs, to save its name and argument values, so that I can use them later. One way I found is to add something like this to each of them:

```
frame = inspect.currentframe()
args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
function_name = inspect.getframeinfo(frame)[2]
function_meta = {arg: values[arg] for arg in args}
self.meta[function_name] = function_meta
```

This is fine, however, I'd prefer to keep it DRY and don't have to copy/paste this identical snippet to *every* method I add.

Alternatively, I could turn it into a separate function `save_meta()`, but then `inspect` will return the data of `save_meta()`, instead of the function that called it, right? Is there any elegant and reusable way of solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only seem to be dependent on the current frame for the `inspect`. I would suggest

```
def save_meta(frame):
    args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
    function_name = inspect.getframeinfo(frame)[2]
    function_meta = {arg: values[arg] for arg in args}
    self.meta[function_name] = function_meta
```

And call it with

```
save_meta(inspect.currentframe())
```

Comment: Ah damn, you're right, that was pretty basic. :) Thanks! Bonus question: is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: @machaerus Sorry, I saw your question just now. What do you mean with easier?

Comment: I thought that maybe there's a way to do this without writing a custom function. It seems like a pretty basic functionality, I'm kinda surprised there's no built-in method for this.

Comment: @machaerus Nothing that I've heard of I'm afraid. If you use it often I guess you could make a super class to subclass from? Otherwise, at least it is quite short :)

Comment: Ok, this method does the trick here, I was just curious. Thanks!